# An exploration of an old, round library

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A youngish boy is brought by his tutor to a large library inside a giant dome, with a single curving path leading higher and higher along the walls.  The higher they go, the more dusty and old the library shelves are.  The ceiling is leaking, and the upper parts of the path are nearly deserted, and have snow falling down.  Written in the 1980s or earlier.

Comment: Possibly The Name of the Rose by Umberto Eco?

Comment: Not Borges' The Library of Babel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel

Comment: Not the Name of the Rose, and definitely not the Library of Babel!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about science fiction or fantasy